# If i wanted to relay data from mobile app games, what would be the best way to do it?

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

If I wanted to make some sort of api so that ANY mobile game for android or iphone could  relay their game stats to our servers, what would my approach be?

My initial thoughts:

develop an api for java and objective c - Would developing an api for these two languages be sufficient for all mobile games? (if not are most games developed using a java or objective c base)

I am new in developing api's, I wanted to know what type of api could I make to make it so any mobile game could relay data pretty much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a web service on your server, which accepts these statistics as input.  The implementation of the web service client can be different for the Android and iPhone, but they are relatively simple to make if you have the WSDL file to generate the clients from.  (The WSDL file is created when you make the server-side service.)